# why does drawing a circle in the northern hemisphere result in an oval?

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I know there is probably some geographical/mathematical/Projection reason, but why does my circle result in a oval polygon? i am trying to draw a circle from a point.

[image: code]

https://jsfiddle.net/mdecker84/1embLyhj/9/

When my Point has coordinates: [0, 0] or in the southern hemisphere i get a perfect circle. I don't know what is going on.

[image]

```js
var map = new ol.Map({
  target: 'map',
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.OSM()
    })
  ],
  view: new ol.View({
    center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([-71.076056, 42.388399], 'EPSG:3857'),
    zoom: 9
  })
});
var layer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: new ol.source.Vector({
    projection: 'EPSG:4326',
    features: []
  }),
});
map.addLayer(layer);
var vectorSource = layer.getSource();

function createCircle(circleCenterX, circleCenterY, circleRadius, pointsToEnd) {
  let angleToAdd = 360 / pointsToEnd;
  let coords = [];
  let angle = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < pointsToEnd; i++) {
    angle += angleToAdd;
    let coordX = circleCenterX + circleRadius * Math.cos(angle * Math.PI / 180);
    let coordY = circleCenterY + circleRadius * Math.sin(angle * Math.PI / 180);
    coords.push([coordX, coordY]);
  }
  return coords;
}

function addMarker(coordinates) {
  console.log(coordinates);
  var marker = new ol.Feature(new ol.geom.Point(coordinates));
  marker.setStyle(new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Circle({
      radius: 5,
      fill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: 'red'
      })
    })
  }));
  vectorSource.addFeature(marker);
}

function addCircle(coords) {
  // var lonlat1 = ol.proj.transform([0, 0], 'EPSG:4326','EPSG:3857');
  // console.log('var lonlat1',lonlat1)
  var circleCoords = createCircle(coords[0], coords[1], 0.2, 180);
  console.log(circleCoords);
  var polygon = new ol.geom.Polygon([circleCoords]);
  polygon.transform('EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');
  polygon = new ol.Feature(polygon);
  vectorSource.addFeature(polygon);
}

addCircle(ol.proj.toLonLat([-7912507.055205271, 5196764.057392394]));
addMarker([-7912507.055205271, 5196764.057392394]);
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.4.3/css/ol.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.4.3/build/ol.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map" class="map"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It should have the same problem in the southern hemisphere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to the earth being a globe. That's really it. It is still a circle but bended on the z-axis

Comment: So there is no way around this? It gets worse in the poles @s.khetcho

Comment: since you are using EPSG 3857, this is an expected behavior because you are centering at the equator. That's why you are getting a circle on [0,0] and gets worse moving north o south. use https://epsg.io/ this helps visualize a solution

Answer (score 4):

Your code is showing in an EPSG:3857 view what would be a circle on the screen in an EPSG:4326 projection, but on the globe longitudes get closer as you move towards the poles.  For a circle on the screen use `ol.geom.Circle`.  But neither would be a circle on the real globe, for that you need `ol.geom.Polygon.circular`

Answer (score 1):

If you want something that appears circular you can use a `drawCircle` function that accounts for the curvature of the earth (however it won't really be a circle on the ground).

```
function drawCircle(point, radius, dir) {
  var d2r = Math.PI / 180; // degrees to radians 
  var r2d = 180 / Math.PI; // radians to degrees 
  var earthsradius = 6378137.0; // 6378137.0 is the radius of the earth in meters

  var points = 32;

  // find the raidus in lat/lon 
  var rlat = (radius / earthsradius) * r2d;
  var rlng = rlat / Math.cos(point[1] * d2r);


  var extp = new Array();
  if (dir == 1) {
    var start = 0;
    var end = points + 1
  } // one extra here makes sure we connect the
  else {
    var start = points + 1;
    var end = 0
  }
  for (var i = start;
    (dir == 1 ? i < end : i > end); i = i + dir) {
    var theta = Math.PI * (i / (points / 2));
    ey = point[0] + (rlng * Math.cos(theta)); // center a + radius x * cos(theta) 
    ex = point[1] + (rlat * Math.sin(theta)); // center b + radius y * sin(theta) 
    extp.push([ey, ex]);
  }
  return extp;
}
```

[live example](http://geocodezip.com/OL_6.4.3_geocodeSanDiego_circlesExample.html)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

```js
var map = new ol.Map({
  target: 'map',
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.OSM()
    })
  ],
  view: new ol.View({
    center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([-71.076056, 42.388399], 'EPSG:3857'),
    zoom: 9
  })
});
var layer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: new ol.source.Vector({
    projection: 'EPSG:4326',
    features: []
  }),
});
map.addLayer(layer);
var vectorSource = layer.getSource();

function drawCircle(point, radius, dir) {
  var d2r = Math.PI / 180; // degrees to radians 
  var r2d = 180 / Math.PI; // radians to degrees 
  var earthsradius = 6378137.0; // 6378137.0 is the radius of the earth in meters

  var points = 32;

  // find the raidus in lat/lon 
  var rlat = (radius / earthsradius) * r2d;
  var rlng = rlat / Math.cos(point[1] * d2r);


  var extp = new Array();
  if (dir == 1) {
    var start = 0;
    var end = points + 1
  } // one extra here makes sure we connect the
  else {
    var start = points + 1;
    var end = 0
  }
  for (var i = start;
    (dir == 1 ? i < end : i > end); i = i + dir) {
    var theta = Math.PI * (i / (points / 2));
    ey = point[0] + (rlng * Math.cos(theta)); // center a + radius x * cos(theta) 
    ex = point[1] + (rlat * Math.sin(theta)); // center b + radius y * sin(theta) 
    extp.push([ey, ex]);
  }
  return extp;
}

function addMarker(coordinates) {
  console.log(coordinates);
  var marker = new ol.Feature(new ol.geom.Point(coordinates));
  marker.setStyle(new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Circle({
      radius: 5,
      fill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: 'red'
      })
    })
  }));
  vectorSource.addFeature(marker);
}

function addCircle(coords) {
  // var lonlat1 = ol.proj.transform([0, 0], 'EPSG:4326','EPSG:3857');
  // console.log('var lonlat1',lonlat1)
  var circleCoords = drawCircle(coords, 20000, 1);
  console.log(circleCoords);
  var polygon = new ol.geom.Polygon([circleCoords]);
  polygon.transform('EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');
  polygon = new ol.Feature(polygon);
  vectorSource.addFeature(polygon);
}

addCircle(ol.proj.toLonLat([-7912507.055205271, 5196764.057392394]), 20000, 1);
addMarker([-7912507.055205271, 5196764.057392394]);
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.4.3/css/ol.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.4.3/build/ol.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map" class="map"></div>
</body>

</html>
```